# Set Active Layer of Multi-layer Map

Tags: leaflet

I have a Leaflet Map with 5 layers, each with multiple map points. From any of 5 separate pages a user can select to view all of the map points for any one of the map layers. The desired type is passed via a URL to the View_All page. The View_All page contains the Leaflet map with the five layers dynamically built for the layers and map points.

What I need is first to set the user desired map layer to be the active layer after the map is fully built. Further, I will need to access the layer control to determine when the user has selected another layer so the page heading can be updated to reflect the type of information being viewed.

[Here is a link](https://www.msholmes.org/map_all/cem/cemeteries) to a quasi finished page.

TIA for any assistance.
jdadwilson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a layer control to your map, and then listening on the `baselayerchange` event.

```
var overlayMaps = {
    "Cemeteries": l1, //l1,l2,... Layergroups or GeoJSON Layer
    "Churches": l2,
    "Markers": l3,
    "Schools": l4,
    "Towns": l5,
};


var text = {
    "Cemeteries": "Test Cemeteries",
    "Churches": "Test Churches",
    "Markers": "Test Markers",
    "Schools": "Test Schools",
    "Towns": "Test Towns",
}

mymap.addLayer(l3); //Acitve Layer from URL
L.DomUtil.get("textheaderid").innerHTML = text["Markers"];


L.control.layers(overlayMaps).addTo(mymap);
mymap.on('baselayerchange',function(e){
    console.log(e)
  var name = e.name;
  var str = text[e.name];
  console.log(str);
  L.DomUtil.get("textheaderid").innerHTML = str;
})
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/q1kmtf93/

Comment: Thanks for the code! Everything works as desired except for one small item. The Page heading does not reflect the heading corresponding to the user request. The requested Layer is activated but the heading is not correct. I changed the text["Markers"] line to everything that I could think of but it always came up as undefined. This is a [link](https://www.msholmes.org/map_all/cem/cemeteries) to the latest code view.

Comment: It would be very useful when you show me your code and not your website without the new code ;) Are your overlayMaps names like `"Cemeteries", "Churches",..` the same as in the `text` `"Cemeteries", "Churches",..`? Else it don't find the right text because this is the reference

Comment: Found the problem. Simple fix, thanks to your comment. Thanks for all your help.